# Is it possible to use the agate module in Python to save databases to MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I was looking for a better way to try to read files and use them to create tables for MySQL, and I stumbled across agate, so I'm trying to see if it will work for my purposes.

I have created the table from a csv file using:
`table=agate.Table.from_csv('testsheet.csv')`

That worked just fine, and I saw agate option to save a db to sql using agatesql and the command:
`table.to_sql('postgresql:///database', 'output_table')`

Is there any way to use this command or to make this module work with MySQL, or will it only work with postgresql? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

As the [Agate SQL API](http://agate-sql.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.2/#usage) docs indicate, the `.to_sql()` method can be *any* valid SQLAlchemy connection string or [SQLAlchemy connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/mysql.html) (Postgres was just the example used):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
...

# CONNECTION STRING
table.to_sql('mysql://user:pwd@hostname:port/database', 'output_table')

# CONNECTION OBJECT
my_engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pwd@hostname:port/database')
table.to_sql(my_engine, 'output_table')
```

If needed you can interface sqlAlchemy with an available DB-API like `pymsql`

```
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
...

# CONNECTION OBJECT    
my_engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@hostname:port/database")

table.to_sql(my_engine, 'output_table')
```